# Errors in implementing Memcache in java

Tags: java, memcached

I'm trying to write a simple code in Java to connect to a memcache server . I using the spymemcached 2.8 jar but I am getting a "server reconnecting" error which I'm unable to understand.

Code is:

```
    **client =  new MemcachedClient(new    BinaryConnectionFactory(),AddrUtil.getAddresses("127.0.0.1:11211"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       System.err.println("connection problem");
    }
     client.set("someKey", 3600, new Integer(10));
    Object myObject=temp.client.get("someKey");
    System.out.println(myObject);
    client.delete("someKey");**
```

But I'm getting errors which are:

```
**2012-06-14 17:58:31.412 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=/127.0.0.1:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
2012-06-14 17:58:31.428 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@1621e42
2012-06-14 17:58:31.428 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Reconnecting due to exception on {QA sa=/127.0.0.1:11211, #Rops=1, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=Cmd: 1 Opaque: 1 Key: someKey Cas: 0 Exp: 3600 Flags: 512 Data Length: 1, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=1}
java.io.IOException: Disconnected unexpected, will reconnect.
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleReads(MemcachedConnection.java:452)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:380)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:242)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.run(MemcachedConnection.java:833)
2012-06-14 17:58:31.428 WARN net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Closing, and reopening {QA sa=/127.0.0.1:11211, #Rops=1, #Wops=0, #iq=1, topRop=Cmd: 1 Opaque: 1 Key: someKey Cas: 0 Exp: 3600 Flags: 512 Data Length: 1, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=1}, attempt 0.
2012-06-14 17:58:31.428 WARN net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.BinaryMemcachedNodeImpl:  Discarding partially completed op: Cmd: 1 Opaque: 1 Key: someKey Cas: 0 Exp: 3600 Flags: 512 Data Length: 1
2012-06-14 17:58:31.444 WARN net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Could not redistribute to another node, retrying primary node for someKey.
2012-06-14 17:58:33.444 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Reconnecting {QA sa=/127.0.0.1:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=1, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=Cmd: 0 Opaque: 3 Key: someKey, toWrite=0, interested=0}
2012-06-14 17:58:33.444 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@1813fac
Exception in thread "main" net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for value
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1003)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1018)
    at ballydev.Memcache.main(Memcache.java:29)
Caused by: net.spy.memcached.internal.CheckedOperationTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for operation - failing node: /127.0.0.1:11211
    at net.spy.memcached.internal.OperationFuture.get(OperationFuture.java:93)
    at net.spy.memcached.internal.GetFuture.get(GetFuture.java:62)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:997)
    ... 2 more**
```

Anyone having any idea or suggestion? .. please reply...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Timed out waiting for operation - failing node: /127.0.0.1:11211`
this means your memcached binded on other adress or it's not started.

Comment: how to know which address it is bounded to ?? I have started the server from services itself... so i hope it is started..

Comment: Do you use unix like os?

Comment: this will be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/1998838/1321404

Comment: No I m using windows xp.

Comment: how you installed memcached in windows?

Comment: I downloaded memcahed tar file, unzipped it into c:\memcached. then from command  prompt i executed c:\memcached\memcahed.exe -d install     and then memcached.exe -d start

Comment: in windows services memcached in started status?

Comment: yes... i restarted the memcached server from services

Comment: in command line prompt just launch "netstat" in give me output

Comment: its showing connection established for localhost:11211 from my computer ip..

Comment: could try to replace 127.0.0.1 with localhost?

Comment: i tried but to no avail.. i have posted a new question regarding new errors ... m getting server unavialable for the given server list to memcachedclient <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046116/memcached-server-is-unavailable?lq=1>

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, there was some problem with my machine, that's why I was having so many troubles running a simple code. But when I tried on a different box and used it's IP den it worked fine... :)

Thanks everybody for bearing this one with me...

Comment: You could explain which was your problem, it could help someone else ;) And then accept your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Till now i am unable to find particular problem but its not just my system, it happened on few other systems also when i tried to run memcached on them. As far as i think reason can be anyone of them:
  ** 1.TCP port 11211 of these system may be used by some other process or blocked by  firewall.                                                                2.May be the installed memcached binaries does not support windows current version.  But since these solutions did provide any help to me, I would like guys to try out more on themselves after trying these.   **

Comment: In such cases, always try commands like telnet 
e.g. telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
This will explain whether the memcached server is actually started/working or not.